# What can be done to improve the speed of Meteor development tool?

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor.  I just start using Meteor for the first time.  It seems a bit slow.  I am developing on a Macbook Pro with SSD.  I am using Firefox, and Vim.  I tend to save the files frequently, causing it to refresh the browser.  It takes a few seconds for the browser to refresh.  I do not have much code yet.  Are you experiencing this slowness?  How can this be improved?  Does MDG have any plan to improve this?  If I make change to a file, can we cause the browser to just reload that file rather than doing a full build and causing the browser to reload all the files?  Am I missing something?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do anything about it. However, the complete rebuild takes place only when you change the server side code. For any client changes, the change is almost instantaneous.

You can try some workarounds by removing some packages from meteor but they will affect debugging.

There is a great thread on this issue on Meteor's Github Issue section. You can find it [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284)

Also, you may consider using WebStorm as it is the only IDE with built-in meteor support. May help you speed up your dev time.

UPDATE: You may try using import functionality in Meteor 1.4 to define file dependencies. Also, have a look at this [package](https://github.com/xolvio/automated-testing-best-practices)